# I am using the primefaces example of the chat, apparently I have an exception when trying to open the channel

Tags: jsf, primefaces, xhtml, prettyfaces

Occurs at the time of loading the page, in addition to the parcer does not find the channel room or can not read some characters.

```
<p:socket onMessage="handleMessage" channel="/{room}" autoConnect="false" widgetVar='subscriber' />
```

Caused by:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: [/context/primepush/{room}] is not a valid URL fragment. Consider encoding relevant portions of the URL with [class org.ocpsoft.urlbuilder.util.Encoder]

my web.xml

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.primefaces.push.PushServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        <async-supported>true</async-supported>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/primepush/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

in my bean

```
 public void login(BLogin log) {
RequestContext requestContext = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
         username=log.getLogNombres()+" "+log.getLogApellidos();
        if(users.contains(username)) {
            //loggedIn = false;
            //FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Username taken", "Try with another username."));
            //requestContext.update("growl");
           // requestContext.execute("PF('subscriber').connect('/" + username + "')");
            loggedIn = true;
        }
        else{
            users.add(username);
            requestContext.execute("PF('subscriber').connect('/" + username + "')");
            loggedIn = true;
        }
    }
```

my xhtml

```
<f:metadata>
            <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{chatView.login(bLoginController.getbLogin())}" />
        </f:metadata>
            <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true"/>
            <p:socket onMessage="handleMessage" channel="/{room}" autoConnect="false" widgetVar='subscriber' />
            <script type="text/javascript">
                function handleMessage(message) {
                    var chatContent = $(PrimeFaces.escapeClientId('form:public')),
                            text = (message.user) ? message.user + ':' + message.text : message.text;

                    chatContent.append(text + '<br />');

                    //keep scroll
                    chatContent.scrollTop(chatContent.height());

                    if (message.updateList) {
                        updateList();
                    }
                }
            </script>
```

I try

```
        <p:socket onMessage="handleMessage" channel="/%7Broom%7D"
```

and other error

```
16:16:21,998 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-16) Error Rendering View[/pages/home.xhtml]: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No parameter [room] was set in the pattern [/context/primepush/{room}]. Call address.set("room", value); or remove the parameter from the pattern.
```

Comment: Please include the relevant code.

Comment: please post the code in the question in the proper format (not as a comment). It's almost impossible to read this way. I've updated your question with the code you originally posted. Since then you've updated your comment. You will get much more answers is your code is easy to read.

Comment: Okay! I still can not find a way to solve it

Comment: You have to be patient. Some questions take days for people to jump in.

Comment: Please make sure you are using the latest version of Rewrite/PrettyFaces. IIRC there has been a fix for this issue in one of the latest releases.

Comment: i using prettyfaces 2.0.12

Comment: The error is pretty clear, you can't use curly brackets in URIs, try encoding them `channel="/%7Broom%7D"`

Comment: i try <p:socket onMessage="handleMessage" channel="/%7Broom%7D"  and other error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to only write / room without the relatives and the connections were created correctly

```
<p:socket onMessage="handleMessage" channel="/room" autoConnect="false" widgetVar='subscriber' />
```

Comment: <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.ocpsoft.rewrite/rewrite-servlet -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.ocpsoft.rewrite</groupId>
    <artifactId>rewrite-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.2.Final</version>
</dependency>

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because Rewrite/PrettyFaces fails to parse the corresponding URL. That is probably because your are using a VERY old version of Rewrite/PrettyFaces from 2013. Please update to 3.4.1.Final. There has been some bugfixes regarding URL parsing in the latest releases and I'm confident that updating will fix your problem.

See:
https://github.com/ocpsoft/rewrite/issues/224

Comment: I Change the version of prettyfaces to 3.4.1 and generate the same error